# Small size compiler for Python 3.6 on windows

Tags: windows, python-3.6, distutils

I'm trying to figure out how to distribute a python program that needs to do on-the-fly compilation via distutils.

On linux it works a treat, as gcc is always installed.
On os/x, xcode is easy enough to get

On windows, the best I can currently find is the community edition of visual studio 2017. Installing the C++ components this is about 4-10 GB.

Is this the only way to get a C compiler for Python on windows (that works with e.g. anaconda)? I know there was a much smaller toolchain (few MB) for 2.7. I've tried installing microsoft's command line build tools, but they don't provide a `vcvarsall.bat`, it seems.

Comment: Why do you compile on-the-fly at the user site instead of compiling once and distributing binary wheels?

Comment: Because I generate the code that I compile depending on the problem that needs to be solved

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: It's either MinGW or Visual C++ build tools.